# How do i get last n line stack using pstack command?

Tags: linux, stack, analysis, pstack

I am using pstack command in my c++ code and storing it in a string. The problem is it prints the stack upto last function and string becomes very heavy. Is there any way to print only last n lines of stack using pstack?

If it can't be done using pstack, then is there any other way to solve this purpose?

Comment: No, pstack prints the whole stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect pstack output to a file
then you can use tail -n to see last n lines

e.g.

```
pstack 243 > File.txt
tail -10 File.txt
```